# OSX - ChromeDriver/Selenium Webdriver issue

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, webdriver, osx-mavericks

I am trying to learn Selenium Webdriver using Python using resources found [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp) - specifically, I want to use Chrome.  I downloaded the ChromeDriver, opened it, and a separate terminal window popped up - looks good.  I then kicked off the sample test in the documentation using Chrome instead of Firefox.  I then get this message -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test1.py", line 7, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
self.service.start()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-2.37.2-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/chrome/service.py", line 68, in start
and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.
Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver'
```

But I have no idea how to do that.  I can't find any example of what that would look like.  I'm not very technical at all, but I would assume that is my bash_profile?  If so, here it is now, if it helps (I have tried using Java/Maven in the past) -

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH"
export M2_HOME=/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.1.1
export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
PATH=$M2:$PATH
export JAVA_HOME=/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH
```

Please let me know if I can provide more information that will help you answer my question, I really want to get this working.  Thanks!

Comment: You are correct that you will have to add the location of your `ChromeDriver` executable to your `PATH` - and on your Mac it is your `bash_profile`. And here's a link on how to add to your `PATH`.